# Create data template with inline timestamp in listview in wp8.1

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create ui given in following picture,
[image]

I have used [richtextblock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.aspx) with runs but how to add inline timestamp and timestamp on right when going to newline.